# Scripting.Dictionary Performance Suffers In Multiple Processes

Tags: c#, dictionary

To illustrate the problem, compile a C# project with a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, and the code below. Run a single instance of the resulting executable. On my 12 core machine, the read loop consistently takes about 180ms. Starting another instance of the executable slows this down, by approximately 100ms per additional executable.

Any ideas what's going on? And any solutions other than switching to a different dictionary implementation?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            var dict = (Scripting.IDictionary)(new Scripting.Dictionary());
            stp.Start();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                Object s = i.ToString();
                dict.Add(ref s, ref s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("After Add {0}", stp.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            object q = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
            {
                long old = stp.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                for (int i = 1; i < 10000; ++i)
                {
                    q = null;
                    object s = i.ToString() as object;
                    q = dict.get_Item(ref s);
                }
                long newval = stp.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine("After Retrieve {0}", newval - old);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scrolling a thousand lines of text across a console while timing code is a really bad idea.

Comment: I wrote `Scripting.Dictionary` in 1997. I have no idea what the cause of your problem is, but I would be curious to find out. Whatever it is, I can assure you it is highly unlikely to ever be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric, you'll be pleased to hear that the problem is not specific to Scripting.Dictionary, but rather with the Apartment threading model. One can read about the performance impact of mixed threading models on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however the surprise (to me) is the out-of-process impact.

I was able to create my own COM object with a single method, as outlined below, replacing the Scripting.Dictionary calls in the above example. I can then switch between 'Apartment' and 'Both' threading models in the Test.rgs file, rebuild, and confirm that the cross-process impact is resolved in an MTA-enabled object.

Moreover, attaching a debugger and pausing the process, then using procexp (from Microsoft SysInternals), one can see the call stack heading off into the kernel, where I assume there is a single queue being managed for the COM marshalling, causing a bottle-neck across the different processes.

Even worse, this slowdown also occurs when marshalling calls to different objects, which is observable by running one application calling into Scripting.Dictionary, a few others calling DoNothing(), and watching all of them slowing down.

For our purposes, we will use an alternative dictionary implementation (although it is possible to change the Scripting.Dictionary threading model, this seems unwise).

I suppose there is still a question outstanding about the inter-process impact of COM marshalling. The recommendation must be to try to avoid Apartment threading in a multi-process environment unless someone has a better answer...?

**Creating The Test COM Object**

- Create a new project in Visual Studio, using the C++ ATL Template (I'm using VS 2008).
- Select server type DLL.
- Right-click the project, Add Class... -> ATL Simple Object.
- Give it a Short Name, e.g. "Test", ensure Apartment threading is selected.
- From the Class View, right-click the interface (ITest), and Add Method...
- Name the method, e.g. "DoNothing", and leave the default options.
- Check the method implementation is empty, and Build.

One can now add a COM reference from the test application and call the DoNothing() method.

Comment: Thanks for the update; glad you figured it out. Incidentally, there was one release of Scripting.Dictionary where it was incorrectly marked as Both, not Apartment. My mistake. You can read the amusing story here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/19/53054.aspx